# $http.post angularjs do not get in to success or error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My code is like this

```
$http.post("../services/myurl.aspx?Param=" + finaldata, '', { 'Content-type': 'text' })
.success(function (pricedata) {
    alert (success)                        
})
.error(function () {
    alert('we have failed to make a connection with the server. Please try after some time');
});
```

When I make this call neither success nor error happens.But the service is called. I am a little confused. can anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you got any error? please check the browser console error???

Comment: You want to maybe put quotes around `success` in `alert`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use service to post data, here is how you could do it.

```
doSomething: function (data, url) {
            return $http({
                url: url,
                method: 'POST',
                data: data
            });
        },
```

and in your controller consume this service as

```
someService.doSomething($scope.MyData, $scope.Url)
        .success(function (response) {
            console.log("Success", response);
        })
        .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log("Error");
        });
```

Comment: +1 for standard coding.  but the OP don't know about `someService` means.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple code....

```
       $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: "../services/myurl.aspx?Param=" + finaldata,
       })
      .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
         var success="success"
          alert (success);// or alert("success")
       })
      .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
           alert('we have failed to make a connection with server. Please try after some time');
       });
```